# reflection transformation about a plane

Tags: geometry

How do I find the transformation matrix  for the reflection transformation about a plane?
I am not able to get it. please explain it to me on some basic plane equation like y+z=1 or something.

Comment: What was your approach ?.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your plane is given in [Hesse normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hesse_normal_form), i.e. in the form

$$ ax + by + cz - d = 0 \qquad a^2+b^2+c^2=1 $$

where $(a,b,c)$ is the unit normal vector of the plane, and $d$ defines the distance from the origin. Then $ax + by + cz - d$ will measure the distance of point $(x,y,z)$ to the plane. Double that distance, and multiply it with the normal vector, and you have the change in position between the point and its image. A bit of trial and error will get the signs right:

$$
x' = x - 2(ax + by + cz - d)\,a \\
y' = y - 2(ax + by + cz - d)\,b \\
z' = z - 2(ax + by + cz - d)\,c \\
$$